# Having trouble saving an object with a foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

This is my first question in the forum.

I'm new to Django and making progress slow. The code I'm working on now throws an error when saving with an object as a foreign key reference.

These are my models:

```
# models.py 

class Make(models.Model):
    name_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name_text


class Autos(models.Model):
     nickname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=CASCADE)
     milage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     comments = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

HTML form that sends the data to the view

```html
<form action="{% url 'auto:addauto' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <label for="nickname">Nickname : </label>
        <input type="text" name="nickname" id="nickname" value="{{ autodetails.nickname }}">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="make">Make : </label>
        <select name="make" id="make">
            {% for item in make %}
            <option value="{{ item.name_text }} ">{{ item }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="milage">Milage : </label>
        <input type="text" name="milage" id="milage" value="{{ autodetails.milage }}">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="comments">Comments : </label>
        <input type="textarea" name="comments" id="comments" value="{{ autodetails.comments }}">
    </p>


    <input type="submit" name = "buttonsubmit" value="Add">
</form>
```

View where the problem exists:

```
# views.py 

def addauto(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    obj = Autos()
    obj.nickname = request.POST['nickname']

    name_text1 = request.POST.get('make')
    make = Make.objects.get(name_text = name_text1)

    obj.make = make

    obj.milage = request.POST['milage']
    obj.comments = request.POST['comments']
    obj.save()

    return redirect('/autos/listautos')

else:
    make = Make.objects.all()
    context = {
        'make': make
    }
    return render(request, 'autos/add_auto.html', context)
```

The above code works with:

```
make = Make.objects.filter(name_text = "some value")
```

I tried the following code as well but no luck:

```
name_text1 = request.POST.get('make')
make = Make.objects.filter(name_text = name_text1)
obj.make = make
```

For the `objects.get()`, this is the error trace:

```
internal Server Error: /autos/addauto
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/harsha/Projects/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/harsha/Projects/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/harsha/Projects/django-projects/mysite/autos/views.py", line 22, in addauto
    make = Make.objects.get(name_text = name_text1)
  File "/home/harsha/Projects/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/harsha/Projects/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
autos.models.Make.DoesNotExist: Make matching query does not exist.
```

I tried everything I could think of based on my current knowledge - it looks like I don't see the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done a the migrations first ? `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes, I have done the migration

Comment: Run django shell `./manage.py shell` , `from atos.models import Make`. And try this query: `Make.objects.filter(name_text='filter_value').first()`. To see if some object with the value `filter_value` as name_text exist

Comment: thanks, it does return "<Make: Honda>"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue and below is my fix.

```html
I was passing "item.name_text" instead of "item.id" for the "value" of the dropdown

<p>
  <label for="make">Make : </label>
  <select name="make" id="make">
    {% for item in make %}
    **<option value="{{ item.id }} ">{{ item }}</option>**
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</p>
```

Updated view with below

```
make = Make.objects.get(pk = request.POST.get('make'))
obj.make = make
```